# DateTime Vs. Date Flow To ProcessPlugin

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, date, datetime, invocable-method

I find this to be odd, not sure if this is a known issue or if it is something I just have to convert but I have a flow that calls a apex process plugin class.

The flow takes a variable of type `Date` and passes that value to the apex class.

[image]

The apex class looks like this:

```
public with sharing class CreatePaymentSchedule implements Process.Plugin {
    public Process.PluginResult invoke(Process.PluginRequest request) {
        Map<String, Object> result = new Map<String, Object>();
        Date varStartDate = (Date) request.inputParameters.get('varStartDate');
        .....
        return new Process.PluginResult(result);
    }
}
```

When I run the flow, I get this error:

EXCEPTION_THROWN|[36]|System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type Datetime to Date

When I change the input parameter to DateTime it works. What gives?

Comment: What is being passed as the `varStartDate` parameter? Can you provide a `System.debug` call for that parameter?

Comment: @RenatoOliveira the debug looks like this: `DEBUG|values:{varStartDate=2018-07-19 07:00:00}` so it is being passed from flow to apex as a date time even though the flow is supposed to be setting it as a date :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in Apex, the `Date` type always has a time component set to zeroes. If you open your developer console and issue a `System.debug(Date.today());` you'll get the following:

> 16:10:46.10 (11087959)|USER_DEBUG|[1]|DEBUG|2018-07-19 00:00:00

Because you get the hours, my guess is that somewhere the platform is passing the `Date` attribute as a `String`, and then when you try to read this as a date in Apex, it will get "confused" because of the hours. You can try to cast your Object to a DateTime instead of casting to Date directly.

Comment: ah that is what I was suspecting. I need to save the value into an object later down in the logic so I am going to have to convert it to a Date. Thank you for your response!